# How i can add icon above page title wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to add icon above the title page (entry-title) ,every page with icon different and dashed circle around , Like that :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU7m4.png)

Comment: Css is an option - so is editing the html and php. and maybe around 10 others possibilities as well.

Comment: I searched a lot and i didn't find a solution